# GPG and SSH encryption of file need help

Tags: ssh, encryption, password, keyrings

I don't know how to use **Password and Keys** in Ubuntu 11.10 , what is the exactly use of this application , and how can we use this for encrypting files?

Please also explain about *ssh keys* and *gpg keys*?

I read help from application but its doesn't go in my mind what it is all about. I have found one interesting link [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/do-encryption-decryption-signing-easily-with-seahorse-linux/). It has helped me some but I still I have doubts.

Kindly make me understand in simple and short way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although both use encryption, and although they might sound the same, they are otherwise unrelated.

### GPG

When you encrypt with gpg, a set of keys is made in ~/.gpg to be used to encrypt and decrypt files / emails.

There is a public key you distribute to others, so they can verify your signatures and encrypt files for you, and a private key you keep, used for decrypting files sent to you.

See : http://www.madboa.com/geek/gpg-quickstart/

### SSH

SSH keys are used to log into ssh servers (rather then passwords). Again there is a public key (you put on the server) and a private key (you keep).

See :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_keys